# Grid view footer template ? In Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In web application [asp.net gridview], i want to display the gridvew without binding data, i mean i have footer template there i kept textboxes and button when user enter and click add then the data will bind to gridview, for the first time [when no data is there] only footer should display. can you help me, thank you. is there any reference to refer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create one table with same fields [to bind gridivew] and bind the data to gridview

```
             DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("WeekNo", typeof(Int32));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);

            dc = new DataColumn("Division", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);

            dc = new DataColumn("Activity_Desc", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);

            dc = new DataColumn("Projects", typeof(Int32));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);

            dc = new DataColumn("MonDay", typeof(Int32));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);

            dc = new DataColumn("TuesDay", typeof(Int32));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);

            dc = new DataColumn("WednesDay", typeof(Int32));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);

            dc = new DataColumn("ThursDay", typeof(Int32));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);

            dc = new DataColumn("FriDay", typeof(Int32));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);

            dc = new DataColumn("SaturDay", typeof(Int32));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);

            dc = new DataColumn("SunDay", typeof(Int32));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);

            dc = new DataColumn("Hid", typeof(Int32));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);
            dc = new DataColumn("SubmitStatus", typeof(Int32));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);

            dc = new DataColumn("TotalWeek", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);

            dc = new DataColumn("Did", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);

            //dc = new DataColumn("Curstatus", typeof(string));
            //dt.Columns.Add(dc);
            dc = new DataColumn("ActivityID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);
            dc = new DataColumn("ProjectId", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);



            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = 0; dr[1] = 0; dr[2] = 0; dr[3] = 0; dr[4] = 0; dr[5] = 0; dr[6] = 0; dr[7] = 0; dr[8] = 0; dr[9] = 0; dr[10] = 0; dr[11] = 0; dr[12] = 0; dr[13] = 0;
            dr[14] = 0; dr[15] = 0; dr[16] = 0; //dr[17]=0;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            GridView.DataSource = dt;
            GridView.DataBind();
            GridView.Rows[0].Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use;

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true">   
<EmptyDataTemplate>
<!-- your html template -->
</EmptyDataTemplate> 
</asp:GridView>
```

Hope this help